# how to scroll to nth item in scrollviewer

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollview

I am writing an application for windows 8 as a college project.
What I have is as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer Background="Green" Name="readingSV"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="15" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">  
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Name="readingSP">  
        <TextBlock Name="tb1" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb2" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb3" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb5" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb6" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb7" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb8" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb9" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb10" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb11" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb12" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb13" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb14" />  
        <TextBlock Name="tb15" />  
    </StackPanel>  
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want to view of scrollviewer to get adjusted to nth item eg tb15 on the loading...

I have tried searching for help but couldn't find an answer which was easy for me to understand

I am actually creating the textblock in codebehind and adding them to the stackpanel which is in the scrollviewer the textblocks will be filled with lines of text from a book lets say... one textblock per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bit of maths...
after all the elements are in place. i calculated the total height of the scroll viewer and calculated the textbox location based on its actual height.